# How to retrieve SMS confirmation code in Appium

Tags: android-emulator, sms, appium

I am running tests to an app with Appium and TestNG. However, I must first log in to the app which requires an SMS confirmation code to be entered. Is there any way I can include this in my code? Some way to intercept that SMS code and enter it in the app?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is click on the OTP inputbox then there would be text to 'Autofill code' and make a wait till your "Verify" button says either is "enabled/checked". Then click on it and proceeds with the test .

2nd Solution would be something i found on appium discussion forum
https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-read-sms-from-native-messaging-app-p-e-to-read-otp/10409

Answer (score 0):

This works well in java, C#, and Python. The returned JSON format is wrong so work on string manipulation to read it. Posting here Java code for your reference.

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability("platformName", "android");
cap.setCapability("appium:deviceName", "mydevice-redmi");
cap.setCapability("udid", "emulator-5554");

AppiumDriver driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
        
HashMap<String, Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
map.put("max", 3);      
String result=driver.executeScript("mobile: listSms", map).toString();      
System.out.println(result);
```